# Application Insights for applications that hosted on my own server

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-application-insights

I've just started working with Microsoft Application Insights and I've started with some videos and [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-get-started/) article on Microsoft website. It seems very powerful and promising.

Can anyone tell me what feature will I loose if I run my applications on my own servers instead of Azure?

P.S:I develop ASP.net applications and use log4net usually for logging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are documentation:

If you can redeploy and application - just install Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web NuGet. Or in Visual Studio click "Add Application Insights". Details are here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-asp-net/

If you cannot redeploy - use Application Insights Status Monitor. You can install it with the Web Platform Installer. Details are here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-monitor-performance-live-website-now/

Logs: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-search-diagnostic-logs/#trace

Comment: Note if you rely on Status Monitor and your enterprise uses SCOM, you'll likely have versioning conflicts between it and SCOM's MMA.

Answer (score 1):

> [W]hat feature will I loose if I run my applications on my own servers
>   instead of Azure?

**None.**

It is completely supported and fully encouraged to monitor your on-premises applications. You actually might gain some better monitoring as you can get Windows performance counters, where as on an App Service (formerly Web Apps) you cannot get things like per process CPU and .NET Runtime counters.

Look at the links [Sergey Kanzhelev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4396426/sergey-kanzhelev) left in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922418/4445931) for details on the Status Monitor and performance counters.